# Difference of BPMN and BPEL

Tags: bpel, bpmn

What's the difference between BPMN (Business Process Model & Notation) and BPEL (Business Process Expression Language) and Where do we use BPMN and where do we use BPEL and which one is better?

Comment: I believe, that this [Blog Post by Leymann](https://leymann.blogspot.com/2009/12/bpel-vs-bpmn-20-should-you-care.html) gives a good explanation and also points out that the previously used techniques for executing BPEL might still live on in more modern BPMN engines.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

BPEL is an XML-based process specification language with a strong focus on automation.

BPMN **started** as a purely graphical business process notation.

Initially and by design, BPMN and BPEL were often used in conjunction (see [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dikmans-bpm-101437.html) as posted in a previous answer): BPMN was used for the business user-centered perspective and BPEL for the technical specification.

In [older versions of the BPMN standard](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/1.1/PDF/) the mapping of the graphical notation to BPEL is a core aspect.

However, with [version 2.0](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF/) an own XML format was added to the BPMN standard. Accordingly, BPEL became less important in a BPMN context, as BPMN now fulfills both business and IT needs.

Currently, the BPMN 2.0 XML format is arguably the most popular standard for transferring process models between systems.

Moreover, a variety of solutions like [Signavio Workflow](http://www.signavio.com/products/workflow/), [jBPM](http://www.jboss.org/products/bpmsuite/overview/) and [Camunda](https://camunda.org/) support the execution of BPMN 2.0 XML.

BPEL, however, might be considered legacy technology.

Answer (score 3):

First of all BPEL is Business Process **Execution** Language.

BPMN is graphical notation of Business processes that an organization has. This is used by Business Analysts.

BPEL is a xml based execution language for the Business process. This is used by Technical analysts.

Both are used for different purposes. So you cannot say which is better.

More details can be found from: [BPMN and BPEL explained](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dikmans-bpm-101437.html)

Comment: The link is outdated. So is your answer. BPMN is not only a graphical notation, but also an XML standard. BPMN XML can be executed by a variety of business process execution engines.